# The proper way to redirect from http:// to /www in IIS7

Tags: rewrite, forwarding, seo, web.config

I've noticed recently that Google and a number of other SEO tools are a little confused about where my site is located. They seem to be unsure about whether it's www. or non www. [SEO Moze's Site Explorer](http://www.opensiteexplorer.org) tool is unsure and so is [Google's webmaster's tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters).

An example of what SEO Moz Suggests.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAkOu.jpg

I've tooled around quite a bit with my WordPress installation and my [web.config](http://pastebin.com/NwTcW5cR) file trying to find the perfect configuration. Though it seems as though I'm not quite there.

Any help and advice would be appreciated.

http://pastebin.com/NwTcW5cR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [this module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite) in IIS.  The tutorial [here](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) is very straight forward to follow.

Here's a sample rule that redirects traffic from sites/sitename/ to my new website.  I would create a site that listens on say http://sitename.com and redirects it to your active site on http://www.sitename.com.

```
<rewrite>
<rules>
<rule name="Redirect to new site" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="sites/sitename/" />
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newsite/sites/sitename/default.aspx" />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: I posted a copy of my web.config file and had been using URL rewrite when I wrote this post. It seems as though I'm pretty close. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not sure which site your trying to redirect.  I've added the rule I use to the answer.